# Loki 0.4 does not boot after install

Tags: release-loki, system-installation, 64-bit

I just installed Loki on my desktop,
ASUS Z87-PRO, BIOS:2103
32GB DDR3 (1866MHz)
i7-4790K
R9 380 (primary)
GTX 970 (secondary)

I have tried installing from USB and DVD, straight install and from the liveCD mode.
It seems as though Grub is not installed by the installer. At boot all I getting is a flashing terminal courser.

On my laptop the install works fine just not my desktop.

Please advise

Following on I remembered I had downloaded the beta early last month and decided to try installing that. For some reason the beta works but the stable version does not. I guess I just have to hope that updating the beta brings me up to the stable

Comment: Same issue here... Do you have a link for the beta iso?  I can't seem to find any mirrors now for that beta! :\

Answer (score 0):

try disabling secure boot in the BIOS see if that helps when you install